# SQL Pivot Grouping Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, count, pivot

I have a table of exam data with a couple of simple rules. The exam has a number of different tracks based on geography and size. A question is either visible or not based on a boolean column called visibility that is either populated with a zero for "not visible" or a 1 for "visible".

Question |
Track |
Visibility

Question_A | North_Large | 0

Question_A | South_Small | 1

Question_A | East_Med.... | 1

Question_B | North_Large | 1

Question_B | South_Small | 1

Question_B | East_Med.... | 1

My code to Pivot the above looks like this :

```
SELECT *
Into Track_Pivoted
FROM Track_Creation
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Visibility)
  FOR [Track] IN ([Question A],[Question B]) as _pivoted
```

The issue is that in the resulting table Track_Pivoted Question A is showing showing a 1 for North_Large where in the original table I am selecting from it is a 0.

I feel like this should be right, but not sure what is happening. My example above is a simplified version of my actual data, which has more like a couple of hundred questions for 40 tracks, but I feel I have represented the issue accurately.

Any help in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand your desired output; maybe this is what you want: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15d58/25 ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are using `COUNT` for your aggregate function. It sees one row with North_Large for Question_A so it returns 1. You may want to change `COUNT` to `MAX` or `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which way you want the pivot, but your existing query has 3 problems:

1. using COUNT() would produce 1 in all cells. Use MAX() instead.
2. You are comparing [Track] to values of [Question]
3. The values you are comparing to don't agree with the data (e.g. underscoreA, not, spaceA)

So, here are 2 alternatives:

Pivot on Question:

```
SELECT *
FROM Track_Creation
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Visibility)
  FOR [Question] IN ([Question_A],[Question_B]) 
 ) as pivoted
;
|        TRACK | QUESTION_A | QUESTION_B |
|--------------|------------|------------|
| East_Med.... |          1 |          1 |
|  North_Large |          0 |          1 |
|  South_Small |          1 |          1 |
```

Pivot on Track:

```
SELECT *
FROM Track_Creation
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Visibility)
  FOR [Track] IN ([North_Large],[East_Med....],[South_Small]) 
 ) as pivoted
;
|   QUESTION | NORTH_LARGE | EAST_MED.... | SOUTH_SMALL |
|------------|-------------|--------------|-------------|
| Question_A |           0 |            1 |           1 |
| Question_B |           1 |            1 |           1 |
```

<kbd>[See this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/15d58/30)</kbd>